# Does it affect the Google Search autocomplete predictions if lots of people click a link to search results?

Tags: google-search

If people type a search phrase in Google enough times, this can end up having an impact on the [Google Search autocomplete feature](https://www.blog.google/products/search/how-google-autocomplete-works-search/) which offers predictions for the remainder of your query as you type.

What if a lot of people click on a link to search results? Would the query for those results also affect this predictive autocomplete?